# Angular 4.2 DSL animation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I`m try to use Angular 4.2 new animation API and create simple example when i try to make fadeIn / fadeOut effects. But it seems that transition fadeOut => fadeIn is not called. Why?

```
trigger('divAnimation', [

   state('fadeIn', style({opacity: 1})),
   state('fadeOut', style({opacity: 0})),

   transition('* => fadeIn', [
    query('span, p', style({transform: 'translateX(-50px'})),

    query('span, p', [
      animate(500, style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
    ])

    ]),

    transition('* => fadeOut', [
      query('span, p', [
        animate(500, style({opacity: 0}))  
      ])

    ])

 ])
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0C5Esoszz7zkCrDeVVoS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
animations: [
 trigger('divAnimation', [

   state('fadeIn', style({opacity: 0})),
   state('fadeOut', style({opacity: 1})),

   transition('fadeIn <=> fadeOut', animate(500))

  ])
],
```

Comment: Yes it works. But i`m really interesting in DSL. And I try to understand why my code doesn`t work?